# How to get multi-categories and products from db as paths

Tags: javascript, mysql, angularjs, node.js, database

### Updated: Data sample

```
DROP TABLE IF EXISTS `tbl_products_categories`;
DROP TABLE IF EXISTS `tbl_products2`;
DROP TABLE IF EXISTS `tbl_categories`;

CREATE TABLE `tbl_categories` (
  `catID` int(5) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `fkAppID` int(5) NOT NULL,
  `parentId` int(5) DEFAULT NULL COMMENT 'η route κατηγορία έχει NULL πατρικη κατηγορία',
  `CatName` varchar(255) NOT NULL,
  `CatPosition` int(5) DEFAULT NULL,
  `CatUrl` varchar(512) DEFAULT NULL,
  `CatAvailability` int(1) DEFAULT '1',
  `CatComments` varchar(255) DEFAULT NULL,
  `CatField1` varchar(255) DEFAULT NULL,
  `CatField2` varchar(255) DEFAULT NULL,
  `CatField3` varchar(255) DEFAULT NULL,
  `CatField4` varchar(255) DEFAULT NULL,
  `CatField5` varchar(255) DEFAULT NULL,
  `CatLastUpdate` datetime DEFAULT NULL,
  `CatDeleted` varchar(1) DEFAULT '0',
  PRIMARY KEY (`catID`),
  KEY `categories_apps` (`fkAppID`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB AUTO_INCREMENT=5057 DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8;

CREATE TABLE `tbl_products2` (
  `prID` int(5) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `PrName` varchar(255) NOT NULL,
  `PrPrice` decimal(5,2) DEFAULT '0.00',
  `PrSPrice` decimal(5,2) DEFAULT '0.00',
  `PrAvailability` int(1) DEFAULT '1',
  `PrUrl` varchar(512) DEFAULT NULL,
  `PrComments` text,
  `PrPosition` int(5) DEFAULT NULL,
  `PrSKU` varchar(255) DEFAULT NULL,
  `PrField2` varchar(255) DEFAULT NULL,
  `PrField3` varchar(255) DEFAULT NULL,
  `PrField4` varchar(255) DEFAULT NULL,
  `PrField5` varchar(255) DEFAULT NULL,
  `PrField6` varchar(255) DEFAULT NULL,
  `PrField7` varchar(255) DEFAULT NULL,
  `PrField8` varchar(255) DEFAULT NULL,
  `PrField9` varchar(255) DEFAULT NULL,
  `PrField10` varchar(255) DEFAULT NULL,
  `PrLastUpdate` datetime DEFAULT NULL,
  `PrDeleted` varchar(1) DEFAULT '0',
  `PrType` varchar(20) NOT NULL,
  `PrVendor` varchar(20) DEFAULT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`prID`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB AUTO_INCREMENT=10450 DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8;

CREATE TABLE `tbl_products_categories` (
  `prId` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `catId` int(11) NOT NULL,
  KEY `products_cat` (`prId`),
  KEY `categories_pr` (`catId`),
  CONSTRAINT `products_cat` FOREIGN KEY (`prId`) REFERENCES `tbl_products2` (`prID`) ON DELETE CASCADE ON UPDATE CASCADE,
  CONSTRAINT `categories_pr` FOREIGN KEY (`catId`) REFERENCES `tbl_categories` (`catID`) ON DELETE CASCADE ON UPDATE CASCADE
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8;

INSERT INTO `tbl_categories` VALUES ('5042', '5', null, 'Phones', '1', null, '1', 'Phones', null, null, null, null, null, null, '0');
INSERT INTO `tbl_categories` VALUES ('5044', '5', '5042', 'SmartPhones', '1', null, '1', 'SmartPhones', null, null, null, null, null, null, '0');
INSERT INTO `tbl_categories` VALUES ('5049', '5', '5042', 'Accessories', null, null, '1', 'Accessories', null, null, null, null, null, null, '0');
INSERT INTO `tbl_categories` VALUES ('5050', '5', '5042', 'iphone', null, null, '1', 'iphone', null, null, null, null, null, null, '0');
INSERT INTO `tbl_categories` VALUES ('5051', '5', '5044', 'ALCATEL', null, null, '1', null, null, null, null, null, null, null, '0');
INSERT INTO `tbl_categories` VALUES ('5052', '5', '5044', 'APPLE', null, null, '1', null, null, null, null, null, null, null, '0');
INSERT INTO `tbl_categories` VALUES ('5053', '5', '5044', 'ASUS', null, null, '1', null, null, null, null, null, null, null, '0');
INSERT INTO `tbl_categories` VALUES ('5054', '5', '5049', 'Θηκες', null, null, '1', null, null, null, null, null, null, null, '0');
INSERT INTO `tbl_categories` VALUES ('5055', '5', '5049', 'HandsFree', null, null, '1', null, null, null, null, null, null, null, '0');
INSERT INTO `tbl_categories` VALUES ('5056', '5', '5049', 'BlueTooth', null, null, '1', null, null, null, null, null, null, null, '0');


INSERT INTO `tbl_products2` VALUES ('10447', 'Product1', '0.00', '5.00', '1', null, null, null, null, null, null, null, null, null, null, null, null, null, null, '0', '', null);
INSERT INTO `tbl_products2` VALUES ('10448', 'Product2', '0.00', '5.00', '1', null, null, null, null, null, null, null, null, null, null, null, null, null, null, '0', '', null);
INSERT INTO `tbl_products2` VALUES ('10449', 'idol4', '0.00', '5.00', '1', null, null, null, null, null, null, null, null, null, null, null, null, null, null, '0', '', null);



INSERT INTO `tbl_products_categories` VALUES ('10447', '5042');
INSERT INTO `tbl_products_categories` VALUES ('10448', '5042');
INSERT INTO `tbl_products_categories` VALUES ('10449', '5051');
```

I have these three tables that I need the combine their results:

**1.** tbl_products  (*all the products*)
 **2.** tbl_categories (*I use `parentId` to have sub-categories*)
 **3.** tbl_product_categories  (*the table that connects products with categories*)

[image]

**The tables , with data** :

[image]

By using the help of [that page](http://sqllessons.com/categories.html), I can get the categories and subcategories 
 as a full path , like:  `Phones->NULL>NULL` OR `Phones -> Smartphones -> Alcatel`

But I also ,somehow, I have to add the products into the results, and I need to get them like this template:

[image]

So, my question is , can I do that in just one SQL query , 
or should I get the results in different queries and then combine them with Javascript code on the client.

Please help me, Thanks.

Comment: Its good to do in chunks, otherwise response rate will be increased and visitor will be annoyed.

Comment: add sample data in text